# Why does my idle connections (MSN/SSH/etc) always disconnect when I'm torrenting? (Using Tomato Firmware)

Tags: router, tomato, qos

My max connections in Tomato Firmware is 8192, and current connection counts at 2000+, so it shouldnt be that.

Any idea what I can do to rememdy this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: What OS do you have?
Can you give more detail about any error messages or log messages you're seeing?
What is the speed of your DSL/Cable/whatever connection? How much traffic are you seeing when you have problems?

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities spring to mind:

- It might be that you're maxing bandwidth in at least one direction on your link. If you have in fact done this, any packets from your MSN/SSH connections could be taking so long to get across the connection that your end (or the other end, depending on which direction is congested) gives up waiting and times out
- It might be that your router simply can't handle so many connections, and is losing track of older connections